# Remove a sub level of an array

Tags: javascript

I get a list of items with add-ons from the server, but when I try to delete an add-on from this list I can't. I noticed that when I try to access the property `grupoAdicionais.produto.codigo`, it does not exist because it has a sublevel coming from the API, how do I remove this to have access to my `product.codigo`?

Array received from API:

```
"grupoAdicionais":[
    {"produto": {"codigo":21, "descricao":"Bacon"}, "item":148657, "quantidade":1, "total":5},
    {"produto": {"codigo":13193, "descricao":"Queijo"}, "item":148657, "quantidade":1, "total":1}
]
```

My code in the reducer to return the list without the extra:

```
REMOVER_ADICIONAL: (state, action) => {
        let itemRemover = action.item;
        let listaReducer = state.lstItensRestauranteQRcode;
        const itemRemovido = listaReducer.filter((item) => {
            return item.grupoAdicionais.produto.codigo != itemRemover.produto.codigo;
        });
        state.lstItensRestauranteQRcode = itemRemovido;
    },
```

Comment: You already have access, but it's `grupoAdicionais[0].produto.codigo`. You're missing the `[0]`.

Comment: I tried this way but when the array has more than one item it always returns the first element, I thought about using a .map inside the Additional group to traverse the elements again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is get a list of the codes:

```
const response = {"grupoAdicionais": [{
  "produto": {
    "codigo": 21,
    "descricao": "Bacon"
  },
  "item": 148657,
  "quantidade": 1,
  "total": 5
}, {
  "produto": {
    "codigo": 13193,
    "descricao": "Queijo"
  },
  "item": 148657,
  "quantidade": 1,
  "total": 1
}]}

const codigos = response.grupoAdicionais.map(grupo => grupo.produto.codigo)

console.log(codigos)
// => 

[ 21, 13193 ]
```

I'm not totally sure, but it seems like maybe you want to remove a group by its code.

```
const removeByCode = (code) => response.grupoAdicionais.filter((group) => group.produto.codigo !== code) 

const newGroups = removeByCode(21)

console.log(newGroups)
// => 

[
  {
    produto: { codigo: 13193, descricao: 'Queijo' },
    item: 148657,
    quantidade: 1,
    total: 1
  }
]
```

Comment: Exactly this second situation, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var response = {"grupoAdicionais": [{
  "produto": {
    "codigo": 21,
    "descricao": "Bacon"
  },
  "item": 148657,
  "quantidade": 1,
  "total": 5
}, {
  "produto": {
    "codigo": 13193,
    "descricao": "Queijo"
  },
  "item": 148657,
  "quantidade": 1,
  "total": 1
}]}

console.dir(response.grupoAdicionais[0].produto.codigo)
```

grupoAdicionais is an array here, you have to access it like this:
console.dir(response.grupoAdicionais[0].produto.codigo)

Comment: I tried this way but when the array has more than one item it always returns the first element, I thought about using a .map inside the Additional group to traverse the elements again.